# How long can deep fried chicken kebab be stored in freezer not fridge

Tags: storage-lifetime, kebab

How long a kabab of following mixture that 
Tomatoes,onions, lemon and minced chicken be stored in freezer rigth after deep frying it to maintain its taste and free of bacteria

Comment: Bacteria will not grow in the freezer, so your concern is quality.  How will you package it for freezing?

Answer (score 0):

Usually a couple of weeks if well packaged (maybe more if put in vacuum bags)

Try freezing them as fast as possible; put them in a single layer on a cooking sheet with space between each kebab.

Once frozen, put them in plastic bags.

Be careful when thawing, vegetables tend to get soggy.